# Laravel Eloquent hasOne. Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I've used Eloquent hasOne to create a relationship between the user and the users_permissions table when the user register's to the website and group the user according to the input they put on the form and it worked fine, but the same method I think it does not recognize when the same user is signed in the website.

**The below code work's when the user sign-up to the website**

```
$user->permissions()->create(UserPermission::user_group($nature_of_entity));
```

**But when I want to use the below method it, I get an error** *Trying to get property of non-object.*

```
public function hasPermission($permission) {
        return (bool) $this->permissions->$permission;
    }

public function permissions() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\User\UserPermission', 'user_id');
    }
```

In the user database a table named users_permissions that has (id, user_id, is_group_one, is_group_two, is_group_three)

I'm trying to see it the user is in which group, like:

```
if($app->user->hasPermission('is_group_one')){
        echo 'Group One';
}
```

But I get an error *Trying to get property of non-object.*
I'd really appreciate it if any can help and if they are ways I could do this and use Laravel Eloquent Relationships methods. I hope you can understand what I mean.

Comment: What do you store exactly in your permissions database?

Answer (score 1):

Create a scope that queries through the permissions relationship and checks if the column (i.e. $permission) is TRUE. Axe the `(bool)` bit...

```
public function scopeHasPermission($query, $permission) 
{        
    return $query->permissions->where($permission, true);
}
```

Then in your controller, keep this the same as you had it:

```
if($app->user->hasPermission('is_group_one')) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error, Trying to get property of non-object...

Comment: public function hasPermission($permission) {
        return $this->permissions()->where($permission, true);
    }

Comment: it worked thanks man. But can how can I see if the hasOne can recognize the logged in user id?

Comment: My example factors in the relationship. The $query is essentially the $user object. It checks if a relationship is already set, if so, queries the `where`. Leave the `public function permissions()` as is. I might be misunderstanding your question. But if you return `return $user->permissions->get()` you should see a result (if you did this in your controller, to test that relationship works as it should)

Comment: Remember to please accept your answer if it worked for you - otherwise you will get limited answers in the future. Also increases your reputation, which in turn will lead to more people answering your questions. I can see you have another question you didn't check off as "answered" too. :)